# Issue Related to Creating an Object of one User Control into Another

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have an asp.net Application i have added some .aspx pages in the root directory..  now i have created folder named `usercontrols` having following structure :

[image]

now i want to call a Method of one user control into another.. but i dont get the class name of any user controls in between..

i have used same namespace in all .ascx.cs file..

so how to call a Method of one user control into another ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference declaration to use the uc within your code:
Add it to your page:

```
 <%@ Reference Control ="~/WebUserControl1.ascx"%>
```